# What iPad app can I use to manage the locations where I took some photos?

Tags: ios, mobile-iphoto

I use iPhoto on the Mac and it can show a map with all the locations where I took photos. Is there a similar app on the iPad? With a map I can zoom in and out…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in one of this choices:

my favorite

[MapProjector with Google Maps](https://itunes.apple.com/sl/app/mapprojector-google-maps/id368998876?mt=8)

Features:

- Create an unlimited number of maps with unlimited landmarks
- Photos - Import photos from your Photo Album using their own locations.

[Exif Wizard](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/exif-wizard/id387652357?mt=8)

Then there is the iPhoto app for iPad :)

Comment: Just like iPhoto on iOS, exif wizard lets you inspect one photo's location on a map, but not map various photos on the same map. One map with all the locations of photos is the goal here I believe.

Comment: @bmike You are so right, so I expanded my answer with few more options.

Comment: MapProjector is exactly what i'm looking for. Please edit your answer to add it at the top, and i'll accept it. Thank you!